Left-join of tables does not work uniformly for every market area
I have three tables in R, df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL (main table), df.unsecuredHI and df.securedHI.
I want to join values ​​(UNSECURED, UNSECUREDMARKETVALUE, SECURED & SECUREDMARKETVALUE) to the main table for each DELIMONTH and MARKETAREA and have to make some preparations beforehand, as there are combinations of DELIVMONTH and MARKETAREA in df.unsecuredHI and df.securedHI that are missing in the main table df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL.
Here you can see the current R-code:
## Create list of all necessary combinations of DELIVMONTH & MARKETAREA: ##
        df.allCombis <- df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL %>%
                        dplyr::select(DELIVMONTH, MARKETAREA) %>%
                        dplyr::bind_rows(
                          df.unsecuredHI %>% dplyr::select(DELIVMONTH, MARKETAREA),
                          df.securedHI %>% dplyr::select(DELIVMONTH, MARKETAREA)
                        ) %>%
                        dplyr::distinct()
        
        ## Identify the missing combinations in the main table df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL: ##
        df.missingCombis <- df.allCombis %>%
                            dplyr::anti_join(df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL, by = c("DELIVMONTH", "MARKETAREA"))
        
        ## Create a DF with missing rows & standard values: ##
        df.missingRows <- df.missingCombis %>%
                          dplyr::mutate(
                            VALUATION = unique(df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL$VALUATION)[1],
                            VALUATIONTIME = unique(df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL$VALUATIONTIME)[1],
                            DELIVYEAR = year(ymd(paste0(DELIVMONTH, "-01"))),
                            BRANCH = "Hedging International",
                            KELAG_ACTIVITY = "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL",
                            REPORTVIEW = "Commodity+Fee"
                          ) %>%
                          dplyr::mutate(
                            dplyr::across(where(is.numeric), ~replace_na(., 0)),
                            dplyr::across(where(is.character), ~replace_na(., NA_character_))
                          )
        
        ## Add missing row-entries to main table df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL: ##
        df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL <- dplyr::bind_rows (df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL, df.missingRows)


        ## _________ HERE starts the problem: _________ ##

        ## Join/Merge unsecured quantities to DFs: ##
        df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL <- df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL %>%
                                           dplyr::left_join(df.unsecuredHI, by = c("MARKETAREA", "DELIVMONTH"))
        ## Check whether double values & order by deliveMonth & replace by NAs for duplicates: ##
        df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL <- df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL %>% 
                                           dplyr::group_by(DELIVMONTH) %>%
                                           dplyr::mutate(
                                             UNSECURED = ifelse(row_number() == 1, UNSECURED, NA),
                                             UNSECUREDMARKETVALUE = ifelse(row_number() == 1, UNSECUREDMARKETVALUE, NA)
                                           )
        
        
        ## Join/Merge secured quantities & secMarketValue to DFs: ##
        df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL <- df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL %>%
                                           dplyr::left_join(df.securedHI, by = c("MARKETAREA", "DELIVMONTH"))
        ## Check whether double values & order by deliveMonth & replace by NAs for duplicates: ##
        df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL <- df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL %>% 
                                           dplyr::group_by(DELIVMONTH) %>%
                                           dplyr::mutate(
                                             SECURED = ifelse(row_number() == 1, SECURED, NA),
                                             SECUREDMARKETVALUE = ifelse(row_number() == 1, SECUREDMARKETVALUE, NA)
                                           )
        ## Ungroup DF: ##
        df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL <- df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL %>%
                                           dplyr::ungroup()

The problem is now:
It correctly links values ​​for the FR MARKETAREA to the DELIVMONTHs, but for the ES MARKETAREA, for example, this does not work. Before all the preparations, ES does not exist in the main table, but only in the unsecured/secured tables, so I had to do all the preparations.
I really do not know what the problem is. I have already checked a few things, such as the unique values ​​and the formatting/structure of the columns in the three tables. Basically, structure and values ​​match, so this should normally fit.
Here is the output of the three tables before the data preparations, where I removed some columns from df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL so that the dput-output is not so huge:
dput(df.unsecuredHI)
structure(list(DELIVMONTH = c("2025-11", "2026-04", "2026-05", 
"2026-06", "2026-12", "2025-01", "2025-12", "2026-02", "2026-08", 
"2025-11", "2025-07", "2026-01", "2025-02", "2025-08", "2025-09", 
"2026-10", "2025-08", "2025-04", "2025-05", "2026-07", "2026-09", 
"2026-11", "2025-12", "2025-01", "2025-03", "2025-04", "2025-06", 
"2025-07", "2025-09", "2025-03", "2025-06", "2025-10", "2026-03", 
"2025-02", "2025-05", "2025-10"), UNSECURED = c(2182.7232, 3287.6907, 
3153.39, 2399.063, 1755.1262, 2108.1984, 1958.0592, 1568.9592, 
1645.7134, 236.6239, 3166.0994, 1056.9933, 2482.3075, 1791.9538, 
1003.0176, 1765.9621, 1018.0131, 4762.0512, 4444.589, 2982.9468, 
878.5574, 2036.9907, 608.0818, 240.8806, 1163.0211, 2152.9276, 
1140.5493, 873.577, 358.094, 5365.8123, 3387.1752, 1894.7958, 
4032.4656, 2433.7632, 1685.865, 0), UNSECUREDMARKETVALUE = c(186924.1573, 
159951.5758, 132489.9577, 105287.099, 149357.938, 203609.8015, 
181711.1677, 152574.6791, 82971.3741, 18614.1183, 205415.7645, 
110555.1172, 252401.0286, 118646.6736, 72124.7565, 117484.1727, 
80334.0916, 302580.7332, 246768.4629, 147958.9157, 48410.684, 
160814.329, 48748.7136, 20115.9392, 61570.3348, 93028.0024, 61045.6349, 
69420.4671, 29170.2654, 442089.2721, 185545.615, 139452.0596, 
315414.1968, 180317.5121, 80962.8318, 0), MARKETAREA = c("FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "ES", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "ES", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "ES", 
"ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "ES", 
"ES", "ES")), row.names = c(NA, 36L), class = "data.frame")

dput(df.securedHI)
structure(list(DELIVMONTH = c("2025-11", "2026-04", "2026-05", 
"2026-06", "2026-12", "2025-01", "2025-12", "2026-02", "2026-08", 
"2025-11", "2025-07", "2026-01", "2025-02", "2025-08", "2025-09", 
"2026-10", "2025-08", "2025-04", "2025-05", "2026-07", "2026-09", 
"2026-11", "2025-12", "2025-01", "2025-03", "2025-04", "2025-06", 
"2025-07", "2025-09", "2025-03", "2025-06", "2025-10", "2026-03", 
"2025-02", "2025-05", "2025-10"), SECURED = c(4320, 5760, 5952, 
5760, 4464, 3720, 4464, 3360, 3720, 0, 3720, 3720, 3360, 3720, 
3600, 4470, 1488, 5760, 5952, 3720, 3600, 4320, 0, 744, 2229, 
1440, 1440, 1488, 1440, 3715, 5760, 4470, 3715, 672, 1488, 0), 
    SECUREDMARKETVALUE = c(369956.3735, 280233.5046, 250073.8063, 
    252787.7291, 379878.0085, 359277.6, 414266.6641, 326745.8629, 
    187549.9792, 0, 241352.6986, 389089.5333, 341644.8, 246304.1379, 
    258867.9635, 297375.7154, 117421.992, 365990.4, 330461.5743, 
    184517.9293, 198368.8914, 341051.0961, 0, 62131.44, 118003.26, 
    62222.4, 77073.1359, 118246.7685, 117302.1194, 306078.85, 
    315526.2657, 328980.4225, 290582.4539, 49788.48, 71460.4641, 
    0), MARKETAREA = c("FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
    "FR", "FR", "ES", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "ES", 
    "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", "ES", 
    "ES", "ES", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "ES", "ES", "ES")), row.names = c(NA, 
36L), class = "data.frame")

dput(df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL)
structure(list(VALUATION = c("294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", "294101", 
"294101", "294101", "294101"), VALUATIONTIME = structure(c(1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 
1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600, 1730073600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), TRADEID = c("1495929", "1495937", "1495937", 
"1495933", "1505383", "1495929", "1495929", "1505383", "1495929", 
"1495929", "1495929", "1495937", "1495937", "1554450", "1505383", 
"1505383", "1505383", "1495937", "1495937", "1495933", "1495929", 
"1495929", "1554450", "1554450", "1505383", "1495929", "1495929", 
"1495937", "1495937", "1495937", "1495937", "1505383", "1505383", 
"1505383", "1505383", "1495929", "1495929", "1495937", "1495937", 
"1495933", "1505383", "1505383", "1495929", "1495937", "1495937", 
"1495933", "1505383", "1495929", "1495929", "1505383", "1495929", 
"1495929", "1495929", "1495937", "1495937", "1554450", "1505383", 
"1505383", "1505383", "1495937", "1495937", "1495933", "1495929", 
"1495929", "1554450", "1554450", "1505383", "1495929", "1495929", 
"1495937", "1495937", "1495937", "1495937", "1505383", "1505383", 
"1505383", "1505383", "1495929", "1495929", "1495937", "1495937", 
"1495933", "1505383", "1505383"), DELIVMONTH = c("2025-04", "2025-01", 
"2025-11", "2025-06", "2026-08", "2025-01", "2025-06", "2026-12", 
"2025-02", "2025-08", "2025-12", "2025-06", "2025-07", "2025-06", 
"2026-11", "2026-04", "2026-07", "2025-03", "2025-08", "2025-05", 
"2025-03", "2025-07", "2025-04", "2025-05", "2026-09", "2025-05", 
"2025-10", "2025-04", "2025-05", "2025-10", "2025-12", "2026-01", 
"2026-02", "2026-06", "2026-10", "2025-09", "2025-11", "2025-02", 
"2025-09", "2025-04", "2026-03", "2026-05", "2025-04", "2025-01", 
"2025-11", "2025-06", "2026-08", "2025-01", "2025-06", "2026-12", 
"2025-02", "2025-08", "2025-12", "2025-06", "2025-07", "2025-06", 
"2026-11", "2026-04", "2026-07", "2025-03", "2025-08", "2025-05", 
"2025-03", "2025-07", "2025-04", "2025-05", "2026-09", "2025-05", 
"2025-10", "2025-04", "2025-05", "2025-10", "2025-12", "2026-01", 
"2026-02", "2026-06", "2026-10", "2025-09", "2025-11", "2025-02", 
"2025-09", "2025-04", "2026-03", "2026-05"), DELIVYEAR = c(2025, 
2025, 2025, 2025, 2026, 2025, 2025, 2026, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 
2025, 2025, 2026, 2026, 2026, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 
2025, 2026, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2026, 2026, 2026, 
2026, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2026, 2026, 2025, 2025, 2025, 
2025, 2026, 2025, 2025, 2026, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 
2026, 2026, 2026, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2026, 
2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2026, 2026, 2026, 2026, 2025, 
2025, 2025, 2025, 2025, 2026, 2026), HEDGINGQUANTITY = c(720, 
2232, 2160, 720, 744, 744, 720, 744, 672, 744, 744, 2160, 2232, 
1440, 720, 720, 744, 2229, 2232, 744, 743, 744, 1440, 1488, 720, 
744, 745, 2160, 2232, 2235, 2232, 744, 672, 720, 745, 720, 720, 
2016, 2160, 720, 743, 744, 720, 2232, 2160, 720, 744, 744, 720, 
744, 672, 744, 744, 2160, 2232, 1440, 720, 720, 744, 2229, 2232, 
744, 743, 744, 1440, 1488, 720, 744, 745, 2160, 2232, 2235, 2232, 
744, 672, 720, 745, 720, 720, 2016, 2160, 720, 743, 744), BRANCH = c("Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International", "Hedging International", 
"Hedging International", "Hedging International"), KELAG_ACTIVITY = c("FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", 
"FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL", "FORWARD HEDGING INTERNAL"), MARKETAREA = c("FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", 
"FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR", "FR"), REPORTVIEW = c("Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", "Commodity+Fee", 
"Commodity+Fee", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", 
"Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", 
"Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", 
"Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", 
"Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", 
"Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", 
"Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", 
"Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity", 
"Commodity", "Commodity", "Commodity")), row.names = c(NA, 84L
), class = "data.frame")


I guess the issue starts here: df.hedgingInternationalINTERNAL %>%  dplyr::group_by(DELIVMONTH) %>% instead of dplyr::group_by(MARKETAREA, DELIVMONTH) %>%. In current state it substitutes NA for all same months regardless of marketareas.

Thank you for your help - now it's working! I've looked at it countless times and never found the bug.
